# how can I resize image to meet height in left in bootstrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to show the image in right side of the top using bootstrap4, but don't know how to resize the image height to meet the same height (keep ratio) as left part

[image]

code (want to remove `200px`)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
           why cannot I still use table for this kind of tasks? why cannot I still use table for this kind of tasks?
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
           It is end of 2021
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
           Now I'd updated to div, this contents can have more text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img width="200px" src="https://www.codeply.com/images/partner_creativetim.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

see https://www.codeply.com/p/flP5E5EpWk

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do... do you mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: Table layout at the end of 2021... That's the first of your problems

Comment: @Kameron when I resize the web page, the left part (text) can be wrapped, the height could be changed, I want the height of the image can be adjusted automatically, but need to keep the ratio now changed

Comment: Yes. If you use Rows and Columns instead of tables this whole image business will be very easy.

Comment: @LarryCai I agree with what Alvaro said, do you have to use a table structure? If not, I can answer with a solution using divs.

Comment: @LarryCai You can try  You can try `@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { img { height: 400px; } }` That allows the height of the image to adjust to height of the table when resizing while maintaining the ratio.

Comment: @Kameron updated with table, not understand how media works here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached it a different way although this may require you to edit the height and width of your image a little.

First I removed the image from that Div and added a class `bg-smile`

```
<div class="col-sm bg-smile">
  <!-- stays empty -->
</div>
```

I've also added `mb-0` to remove the bottom margin from the 3rd text box so the image exactly lines up at the bottom.

Then added a few CSS instructions for the new class and to make the smile image a background of the Div and center it.

```
.bg-smile{
  background: url(https://www.codeply.com/images/partner_creativetim.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thx, can you share complete code?

Comment: @LarryCai Exactly as above my friend. Edit the Div as above and add the above CSS. In essence it is just creating a background in that Div rather than the image being inserted on the page in HTML so you could go about it a few different ways. The point is making a background in the Div.